# The more request means slower read from cached objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, .net-remoting

Please do not judgme for the type of question. It might be about software algorithms and concepts. That is why I must write [the link](https://serverfault.com/questions/948249/slow-response-from-iis-for-different-type-of-requests) that it is already asked on server fault.

**1- > the algorithm and concept of project .net web app.**

> Client's onblur event makes an ajax call-> UI -> functionUI() -> > APP
>   <<

```
functionUI()

int limit=450;
public bool functionUI(){

for(int i=0;i< limit ; i++){
 functionApp(i);
}

}


public static bool functionApp(int i){
 foreach(HolidayEntity h in Global.holidayGlobals.Values /*CachedList*/){
  if(h.Value == i){
return false;
}
return true;
}

}
```

**2- The question**
 The limit value from ui side if it is 2 or 20 times the response duration is good . But when it is 450 times. It takes 40 seconds to get a result in client side. I know the code is not well organised but the question is why the application side so slow when it is responsible to make more calculations.

Any clue will be so usefull. Thank you.

> > Servers are Server 2018 SP 1, .net Frame Work 4.0.30319.42000 
> >     It is only happened in production environment. **In development side the application runs quite fast even the limit is 450.**

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n).  You need a dictionary.

Comment: it is a cached db dictionary. @SLaks

Comment: There are various performance profilers for such troubleshooting. It is pointless to discuss without a reproducible sample.

Comment: IIS diagnoise result : GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START takes 47 ms @LexLi so what it does mean  ? I could not find any documentation about this.

Comment: to who voting for close; There is a case between the algorithm and the characteristics of the server. So please stay calm and let's find out the reason. I promise if I find an answer  I will share it with you here.

Comment: "I could not find any documentation"? Google easily returned this to me, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/12/13/general_read_entity_start/

Comment: @LexLi in the article it is only said it can be a geographical situation. Well noted and commented int that article but could not get a feedback yet. Any idea about  GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START  what does it do on IIS . How to accelerate it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The question is unclear. 40s for 450 function calls appears like network round-trip/context-switch on each iteration. Please specify what function is called on the server, which on the client. Also, I suspect that `Global.holidayGlobals.Values` is not stored in-process and comes from another process like a  memory cache.

Comment: Can you show how `Global.holidayGlobals.Values` is defined?

Comment: @GabrielLuci  Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Comment: So `Global.holidayGlobals` is a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Is `holidayGlobals` a property where the getter is getting the data from another source every time it is accessed? Or is it just defined as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue> holidayGlobals { get; set; }` (empty getter and setter)?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Once it is set to   private static HolidayInfoCache internalGlobalsHoliday; then it will be get from the static file according to Cache Load strategies. It means it has a well designed cache mechanism.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you mean. Would you update your question to include that code?

Comment: @GabrielLuci can not share due to the privacy concern of the company.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you then. In the code you've posted, the only thing that could possibly take more time is the getter for `Global.holidayGlobals`.

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) where the different parts of the code in the question is running. What part is running in the browser, and what part on the server? To me it *looks* like the browser is doing 450 requests to the server. Is that so? If so, network latency is most likely the problem, combined with Session state handling in Asp.Net (one session-enabled request at a time can process).

Comment: @user1429080 client enters a number(eg.450) a text box, on blur event, it calls functionUI js method. It makes an ajax request to UI server. In ui server there is a service method and it makes a call 450 call to functionApp and functionApp is located in app server. client , app and ui are different pc and servers. All internal network. PROD environment Download speed seems normal comparing to TEST environment. GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START  related to network speed?

Comment: @BilginKılıç Your sample code does something else, I write my understanding, please let us know which one is wrong:  
1-`functionUI` is on client side.   
2-`functionUI` calls `functionApp` 450 times (not once with 450 as argument)  
3-`dunctionApp` is on server.  
I understand these from your comments:  
4-`functionUI` calls functionApp once  
5-`this call is slow on PROD and fast on TEST  
but #4 contradicts #2.  Please write more clear code, with comments that show what code is on server and what on client.

Comment: @AliReza finally a nice question.: It is a duration in an operation among 450 operations. ( functionApp() is a unique operation i mean here. its definitions is declared in question ) 
It take 0 ms in test environment but in prod it takes time.

Comment: @BilginKılıç after reading everything on this question so far, it is still unclear to me the way you structured your question and the way you answer to people's questions.

Answer (score 6):

Basically this type of slowness comes from making this mistake:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
   // do a network-roundtrip/remoting/io/etc
}
```

and the solution is to change it to:

```cs
// do a network-roundtrip/remoting/io/etc
for (var i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    // do something with the result of the above call
}
```

So if I've understood you correctly, the data `Global.holidayGlobals.Values` comes from another process, like a memory cache. If so, your easiest bet is to change your code to:

```cs
int limit=450;
public bool functionUI()
{
    var holidays = Global.holidayGlobals.Values;
    for(int i=0;i< limit ; i++)
    {
        functionApp(i, holidays);
    }
}


public static bool functionApp(int i, IEnumerable<HolidayEntity> holidays)
{
    foreach(var h in holidays)
    {
        if(h.Value == i)
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

We are still doing too much work in the loops (we can improve the algorithm by creating a dictionary and just looking it up) but for your number (450) this is negligible compared to the time of one roundtrip to memory cache.

**UPDATE**

From the comments to the question, it appears that `holidays` is `Dictionary<int, HolidayEntity>` if so, the code can become much better like this:

```cs
public bool functionUI()
{
    var holidays = Global.holidayGlobals.Values;

    for(int i=0;i< limit ; i++)
    {
        functionApp(i, holidays);
    }
}

public static bool functionApp(int i, IEnumerable<HolidayEntity> holidays)
{
    if (holidays.TryGetValue(i, out var h))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: than you but i need to accelerate the iis without code modification

Comment: @BilginKılıç If the slow response is due to slow code, I expect that no iis tweak will solve it.

Comment: the same code is running on test environment and it is quite fast since GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START takes 0 ms. But in prod environment it takes 50 ms more or less. Of course code modification can resolve it but the point is why the difference occurs

Comment: so why the prod server slower then test environment. the same codes . so please focus on the details  we need to find out GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START .

Comment: @BilginKılıç Please be a bit more specific. What is 50ms? The time between GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START and GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END? or Between GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START and it's previous event?

Comment: finally a nice question.: It is a duration in an operation among 450 operations. ( functionApp() is a unique operation i mean here. its definitions is declared in question ) 
It take 0 ms in test environment but in prod it takes time.

Comment: The production server hardware setup, Is it superior, (i.e., the number of cores) then the test servers ?

Comment: @BilginKılıç do you like us to use chat? We might try to pinpoint the cause of the problem.

Comment: @mukeshjoshi equal

Comment: @Alireza kindly asking , what do you mean? I have a very simple question in isapi module GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START and GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END? or Between GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START and it's previous event? I have given all the details. You insist on the algorithm. But i have another point . Please be kind.

Answer (score 1):

slowness could be due to the hardware on the server for eg:- Ram, processor. and the services or applications running in the background on the server.